# How to use Google gcloud commands with terraform scripts

Tags: azure, terraform, gcloud, google-cloud-dns, azure-dns

I am creating a AZURE DNS zone & NS records using a terraform script.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dns_management" {
name     = "dns-managment"
location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "mydomaincom" {
name                = "mdomain.com"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.dns_management.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "projectmydomain" {
name                = "project"
zone_name           = "${azurerm_dns_zone.mydomaincom.name}"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.dns_management.name}"
ttl                 = 300
records             = ["127.0.0.1"]
}
```

I want to copy these AZURE NS record to a gcp cloud DNS managed zone. I am trying to do that with `Gcloud commands` using terraform script. How to use Gcloud commands with Terraform?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Do you mean you want to execute the program **gcloud** inside your Terraform HCL or do you want gcloud to read/process your Terraform HCL? Edit your question to clearly state your problem with a detailed description.

Comment: I don't know how helpful this is, but the Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) and both GCP Terraform providers (`google` and `google-beta`) make use of the GCP REST API (more on that [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/reference/v1)).

Comment: If you have at least one Google Kubernetes Engine cluster running in the Google Cloud Platform project you wish to generate this IaC for, you could also look into Config Connector [here](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/dns/dnsmanagedzone).